# why FirstPersonCameraController {camera: camera } not working with QML ApplicationWindow?

Tags: python, pyqt, qml, pyqt5, qt3d

I am loading a QML 3D scene from PyQT5 within an ApplicationWindow.
however, I am not able to pan and rotate my custom model with the mouse.

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Scene3D 2.12

import Qt3D.Core 2.12
import Qt3D.Render 2.12
import Qt3D.Input 2.12
import Qt3D.Extras 2.13

import QtQuick 2.12 as QQ2

ApplicationWindow{   

    Scene3D {
            id: scene3d
            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.margins: 10
            focus: true
            aspects: "input"

            FirstPersonCameraController {
                            camera: camera
                            }

            Entity {
                id: sceneRoot


                Camera {
                    id: camera
                    projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
                    fieldOfView: 45
                    nearPlane : 0.1
                    farPlane : 1000.0
                    position: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 40.0 )
                    upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 )
                    viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )


                    PointLight{
                        id:pl3

                        }
                }



                ObjectPicker{
                  id: spherePicker
                  onPressed:{
                     console.log("Sphere clicked")
                  }
            }
                components: [
                    RenderSettings {
                        activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                            camera: camera
                            clearColor: "transparent"
                        }
                    },
                    InputSettings { }
                ]

                PhongMaterial {
                    id: material
                    diffuse:Qt.rgba(0.5,0.5,0,1)
                }



                 PointLight{
                    id:pl2

                    }

               Mesh {
                    id: esh
                    source: "egg1.obj"

                    }

                Transform {
                    id: torusTransform
                    scale3D: Qt.vector3d(5, 5, 5)
                    rotation: fromAxisAndAngle(Qt.vector3d(1, 1, 0), 45)
                }

                Entity {
                    id: torusEntity
                    components: [ esh, material, torusTransform,spherePicker ]
                }

            }
        }


}
```

The model loads correctly just that I am not able to control it's rotation wit the mouse.

I am thinking this has got to do with the "FirstPersonCameraController"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to verify this myself at the moment but I assume you have to move your `FirstPersonCameraController` within your root entity called `sceneRoot`.

Right now it is a child of the `Scene3D`. Try to move it below the `Camera` node and see if that works.

By the way: I'm assuming that you mean you can't control the camera and that's what you want when you say

> The model loads correctly just that I am not able to control it's rotation wit the mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my work that I am currently using to rotate and translate object from its position. `

```
Scene3D
{
id:myScene3d

property int rotX:0
property int rotY:0
property int rotZ:0`

Entity
{

    id: sceneRoot


    Camera
    {
        id: camera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 2
        aspectRatio: 16/9
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 20.0
        position: Qt.vector3d(posX,posY,posZ)
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )                                  
    }

    FirstPersonCameraController
    {
        camera: camera
        linearSpeed: 1.0
        acceleration: 0.1
        deceleration: 1.0
    }


        Entity
    {
        id: monkeyEntity
        components: [
            SceneLoader
            {
                id: sceneLoader
            },
            Transform
            {

                rotationX  :   rotX
                rotationY  :   rotY
                rotationZ  :   rotZ
            },

            ObjectPicker
            {
                onPressed: {
                    console.log("Object clicked! Pressed at world-intersection: ", pick.worldIntersection)
                    console.log("Triangle index: ", pick.triangleIndex)
                }
            }

        ]
```

As you see rotX, rotY and rotZ are used as property from outside the Scene.
then I have simply used case statements on MouseX and  MouseY values. I hope you got it.
        }